# Android - Adding content to another tab onclick

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Hey guys I have a soundboard with Buttons and all works great. I started messing around with TabHost to make all my sounds in one tab, then ON LONG PRESS the user has the option to save a sound to a Favorites tab or as a Ringtone. The ringtone part works, but I dont know how to save the sound to the Favorites tab.

Right now the app works fine as far as playing sounds in the first tab and such, but I am lost on how to make my buttons appear in my Favorites tab!

HERE's MY MENU:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Favorite");

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == "Ringtone") {
        getButtonPressed(item.getItemId());

    } 
    else if(item.getTitle() == "Favorite"){


    }


            else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is what my buttons look like:

```
Button s67 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button67);
    s67.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote67));
    s67.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            tempId = R.raw.sandcastles;
            setId(tempId);

            try {
                playSound(tempId);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
    registerForContextMenu(s67);
```

I'm guessing I need some kind of method to pass a parameter to when item.getTitle() is equal to "Favorite" but I just need a swift kick in the right direction. Please advise! Thanks!

Comment: I think whenever user wants to save the the ringtone as favorite you can pass  as extra it through `Bundle` or `intent` and then in `oncreate()` of Favourite tab you can retrieve the content and display it.